# How can I add access to use here -1 (instead 0)? Vote negative

Tags: django, django-urls

```
url(r'^rate/(?P<id_obj>\d+)/(?P<rate>\d{-1,1})/', 'app.views.add_rate'),
```

How can I add access to use here `-1`:
`(?P<rate>\d{-1,1})`

This is negative Vote(-1) or positive (1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If value is either `1` or `-1` then you simply need `(?P<rate>-1|1)`

Comment: Convert `rate` into an `int` in your view - `int('-1')`.